# Forwarding communication in app

Tags: ios

Where to start to develop app in xcode that forwards incoming calls, texts, and vmails from unknown numbers to an an ios device directly to an app.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

There is no ability in iOS to intercept and obtain call/text information. Unless your app is not intended for the app store in which case you can use private APIs to obtain this information, but even then with iOS 9 its now no longer possible to get the incoming phone number even if you do use private APIs.